# .Net Maui CollectionView Running 100x Slower on IOS than Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui, collectionview

Below code works well on Android and I can see populated data at collectionview in 2 seconds. But when I try it on IOS it takes approximately 60-65 seconds.

When I debug on IOS, it appears that problem is not about getting the data from database. It only takes 0.5 secs. But after that, filling collectionview with that data and showing it on UI takes about 1 min. But on Android, there is no problem.

Note: Android tested on emulator(Pixel 4 - API 33) in debug mode,
IOS tested on my local Iphone 11 device in hot reload debug mode,
Framework: .Net 7.0,
Data Count Comes From Database: 729 Rows

**View:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Hm.View.Dava_Dosyalari.GetFilesPage"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Hm.Model"
         xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:Hm.View.Files"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Hm.ViewModel.Files"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:FilesViewModel"
         Title="Files">
<Grid RowDefinitions="40, *">
    <Frame Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" Padding="0">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <SearchBar Grid.Column="0" x:Name="searchBar" TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding TotalCount, StringFormat='Total: {0}'}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <RefreshView Margin="10" 
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Command="{Binding GetFilesCommand}"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
        <ContentView>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding files}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <StackLayout Padding="50" Spacing="10">
                        <Image Source="aa.png" Aspect="AspectFit"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="Wait for getting files..."
                           Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.EmptyView>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Files">
                        <Grid Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <Frame HeightRequest="150" CornerRadius="20">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:FilesViewModel}}, Path=GoToFileCommand}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="2">
                                    <Label FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Text="{Binding attr1, StringFormat='Attr1: {0}'}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Label FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Text="{Binding attr2, StringFormat='Attr2: {0}'}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Label FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource MicroLabel}" Text="{Binding attr3, StringFormat='Attr3: {0}'}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Label FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource MicroLabel}" Text="{Binding attr4, StringFormat='Attr4: {0}'}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ContentView>
    </RefreshView>

    <ActivityIndicator
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public partial class FilesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isRefreshing;
    

    FilesService fileService;

    public ObservableCollection<Files> files { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Files> _allfiles { get; set; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    string totalCount;

    public FilesViewModel(FileService service)
    {
        fileService = service;
        GetFilesCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetFilesAsync()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            var fileList = await fileService.GetFilesFromDb();

            if (files != null || files.Count > 0)
                files.Clear();
            if (_allfiles != null || _allfiles.Count > 0)
                _allfiles.Clear();

            await App.Current.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                fileList.ForEach(i => files.Add(i));
                fileList.ForEach(i => _allfiles.Add(i));
                TotalCount = files.Count.ToString();
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Warning", ex.Message, "OK");
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsRefreshing = false;
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GoToFileAsync(Files files)
    {
        if(files== null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(GoToFilePage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"Att1", files },
            {"Id", files.id }
        });
    }
}
```

So far I've tried removing RefreshView from view, remove dispatcher from viewmodel GetFiles command. But nothing works it is still very slow on IOS.

Is something wrong about my code or this is just about .net maui?

Thanks.

Comment: try using an `ObervableRangeCollection` instead

Comment: @Jason Thank you very much I switched to the ObservableRangeCollection and change .Add to .AddRange and now it is almost better than Android version. If you can write this as an answer I can tag it to the accepted answer. And if you dont have time for this I can write the solution cus I know so much people having this problem and there is no clear answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `ObervableRangeCollection` instead and use it's `AddRange` method.  This allows you to add multiple items to a collection without it firing a `CollectionChanged` event for each new item